# How to test a model instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am having some troubles with implementing a Rspec. I have three models; `Post`, `Tagging`, and `Tag`.

#### app/models/tag.rb

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  # associations
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings

  # validations
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  # returns a list of posts that are belonging to tag.
  def posts
      ...
  end
end
```

I was able to write specs for associations and validations but stuck at writing a spec for the instance method of `def posts ... end`. Can someone briefly explain how to write this spec? I am new to Rspec so please bear with me.

#### spec/models/tag_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Tag, type: :model do
  describe "Associations" do
    it { should have_many(:posts).through(:taggings) }
  end

  describe "Validations" do
    subject { FactoryBot.create(:tag) }

    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).case_insensitive }
  end

  describe "#posts" do
    # need help
  end

end
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using association and method with same name?  I'm sure you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
describe '#posts' do
  before do
    let(:tag) { Tag.create(some_attribute: 'some_value') }
    let(:tagging) { Tagging.create(tag: tag, some_attribute: 'some_value') }
  end

  it "tag should do something" do
    expect(tag.posts).to eq('something')
  end

  it "tagging should do something" do
    expect(tagging.something).to eq('something')
  end

end
```

That will allow you to test the instance methods on `Tag`. Basically you want to build the objects that you want to test in a before block and call instance methods on them in the `it` blocks.

Comment: Did you know `let :tag { ... }` isn't a valid Ruby code?.